# How to get location from specific provider in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, geolocation

As Windows Phone 8 uses different provider like, Network, WiFi, GPS, to get location. Is it possible specially to get location from specified provider? Specifically, if I need location only from GPS, which API I should use?

In Android it is possible to find location from specific provider, seeking for same functionality in WP8.

[How to use the .NET Location API for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207054%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> The Microsoft Location Service allows you to create location-aware applications for Windows Phone. The service obtains location data from multiple sources such as GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular. It can use one or more of these sources to deduce the location of the Windows Phone, balancing performance with power utilization depending on an application’s needs.

Comment: best example go to here:[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: Why do you need it from a specific provider? There's a whole criteria framework and a fused location provider specifically designed so that you can worry about power usage rather than what provider you are calling.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Its our business requirement, and lots of algorithm are based on it.

Comment: You're asking two questions here, one for WP8 and one for Android. Hard to get one answer that will have both answers

Comment: @ShawnKendrot No I am asking about WP8, I am saying it is possible in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Which method is used (GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular) depends on the properties set for the Geolocator. [DesiredAccuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.desiredaccuracy%28v=win.10%29.aspx) and [DesiredAccuracyInMeters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.desiredaccuracyinmeters%28v=win.10%29.aspx) are key here. When DesiredAccuracy is set to High it will use the best means available on the device. Likewise when DesiredAccuracyInMeters is less than 100.

Note that when DesiredAccuracy is set to [high](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.positionaccuracy.aspx) the Geolocator will:

> Deliver the most accurate report possible. This includes using services that might charge money, or consuming higher levels of battery power or connection bandwidth. An accuracy level of High may degrade system performance and should be used only when necessary.

Comment: +1 Yes, means I can only guess, but I cannot specify?

Comment: If GPS is not on the device how can you say to use GPS? Think low end phones here. If DesiredAccuracy is set to High, and GPS is available, it will use gps. See my additional note I added.